# node.js reliable microtime setTimeout?

Tags: node.js, microtime

How do I shoot an event EXACTLY after given time in milliseconds? Is there any module for that? I was looking for it on google, but didn't find anything satisfactory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control exact execution of code in the Event Loop. If you need this, then you should look at using a different Framework/Language.

[Understanding the Node.js Event Loop, Timers and `process.nextTick()`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick)

There are no guarantees of when `setTimeout()` will run, only a guaranteed minimum of how long it will wait, see below excerpt from the above guide:

> `setTimeout()` schedules a script to be run after a minimum threshold in ms has elapsed.

[The closest you have is `process.nextTick()` and even then you're at the mercy of the Event Queue because other things queued with `process.nextTick()` can occur before yours.](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick) This is also dangerous due to possible starvation of the Event Loop if not implemented correctly.

Comment: @FlashThunder `libuv` and the Node Core API are implemented with C but they don't expose that level of control to you. A big benefit of working with Node is the abstraction of asynchronous event scheduling.